# How do you take advantage of Metal 3's argument buffers in swift?

Tags: swift, buffer, metal

In Metal 3, argument buffer's are able to be accesed (from my understanding) by passing a memory address in the form of a uint64_t, with the gpuAddress of a buffer.

obj c

```
struct Scene
{
    // The array of instances.
    uint64_t instances;
    uint64_t meshes;
};


id<MTLBuffer> sceneArgumentBuffer = [self newBufferWithLabel:@"sceneArgumentBuffer"
                                                          length:sizeof( struct Scene )
                                                          options:storageMode
                                                        trackedIn:sceneResources];

// Set `Scene::instances`.
((struct Scene *)sceneArgumentBuffer.contents)->instances = instanceArgumentBuffer.gpuAddress;
    
// Set `Scene::meshes`.
((struct Scene *)sceneArgumentBuffer.contents)->meshes = meshArgumentBuffer.gpuAddress;
```

and then in metal as

```
struct Scene
{
    // The array of instances.
    constant Instance* instances [[ id( AAPLArgmentBufferIDSceneInstances ) ]];
    constant Mesh* meshes [[ id( AAPLArgumentBufferIDSceneMeshes )]];
};
```

This is then interpreted as a pointer by metal to a buffer, which has been deployed using the "computeEncoder.useResource" function. Though I am have tried and am not sure how to do this in swift.

Below is my attempt

In the header file I have

```
#if __METAL_VERSION__

struct ShaderMesh
{
    constant VertexColourData* generics;
    constant float3* normals;
    constant float3* positions;
    constant SubmeshInfo* submeshes;
};

#else

struct ShaderMesh
{
    uint64_t generics;
    uint64_t normals;
    uint64_t positions;
    uint64_t submeshes;
};

#endif
```

then

```
sceneResources.append(submeshBuffer)
obj.shaderMesh.submeshes = submeshBuffer.gpuAddress
sceneResources.append(obj.normalBuffer)
obj.shaderMesh.normals = obj.normalBuffer.gpuAddress
sceneResources.append(obj.modifiedVertexBuffer)
obj.shaderMesh.positions = obj.modifiedVertexBuffer.gpuAddress
sceneResources.append(obj.vertexColourDataBuffer)
obj.shaderMesh.generics = obj.vertexColourDataBuffer.gpuAddress
meshes[i] = obj.shaderMesh
```

Where meshes is bound to a `meshBuffer` and `sceneResources` is just used to store the resources that will be sent to the `computeEncoder` and are referenced by the `meshBuffer` using

```
computeEncoder.useResources(sceneResources, usage: .read)
```

I pretty much expected this to work, however, in the metal debugger, when I view the resource that includes the shaderMesh objects, it displays the error "Not a valid buffer"

I have tried using both the question and the answers method from [this post](https://www.stackoverflow.com/), though it doesn't work

Any help would be appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: You need to call `useResource` not on the argument buffer itself, but on all of its contents. So you would call `useResource` on `infoBuffer`, the buffer that contains `normals,` positions` and so on.

Comment: That is what I have done, I will try to make the post a little more clear. Thank you

Comment: This was a while back, but it seems that it was actually a bug with the metal debugging tools. So this question is redundant, but if anyone has the same issues, Disabling Shader Validation solved it (but it might be fixed now ¯\_(ツ)_/¯ )